# Display format currency automatically on span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript code is like this :

```
var format = function(num){
    var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""), parts = false, output = [], i = 1, formatted = null;
    if(str.indexOf(",") > 0) {
        parts = str.split(",");
        str = parts[0];
    }
    str = str.split("").reverse();
    for(var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
        if(str[j] != ".") {
            output.push(str[j]);
            if(i%3 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                output.push(".");
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    formatted = output.reverse().join("");
    return(formatted + ((parts) ? "," + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : ""));
};
$(function(){
    $("#currency_one").keyup(function(e){
        $(this).val(format($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

My full code and demo is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/s6rCN/544/

I want display like this :

[image]

id named currency_one (textfield first), it works

id named currency_two (textfield second), it does not work

I'm still confused to display it automatically on span tag or label like image above

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt call the "keyup" function on the second element.

Do you mean something like this?

```
$("#currency_two").keyup(function(e){
    $(this).next('span').text(format($(this).val()));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s6rCN/552/